# preventing R nested list from being converted to named vector

Tags: r, list, vector, nested, named

I want to create a nested list, for example,

```
> L <- NULL
> L$a$b <- 1
> L
$a
$a$b
[1] 1
```

Since I need to do assignment in loops, I have to use the brackets instead of the dollar, for example,

```
> L <- NULL
> a <- "a"
> b <- "b"
> L[[a]][[b]] <- 1
> L
a 
1
> b <- "b1"
> L[[a]][[b]] <- 1
Error in L[[a]][[b]] <- 1 : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

That is out of my expectation: L becomes a named vector rather than a nested list. However if the assigned value is a vector whose length exceeds 1, the problem will disappear,

```
> L <- NULL
> L[[a]][[b]] <- 1:2
> L
$a
$a$b
[1] 1 2
> b <- "b1"
> L[[a]][[b]] <- 1
> L
$a
$a$b
[1] 1 2

$a$b1
[1] 1
```

Most of my assignments are longer than 1, that is the reason my code seemingly worked but at times failed strangely. I want to know if there is any way to fix this unexpected behavior, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a bug, or at least something strange in assignment functions. Note the difference between these: `L <- list(); L$a$b <- 1; is(L$a)` and `M <- list(); M[["a"]][["b"]] <- 1; is(M$a)`.

Comment: Most surprising is that after setting `L[[a]][[b]] <- 1`, getting `L[[a]][[b]]` will give an error.

Comment: @flodel, do you use `a` or `"a"`? I get no error using strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explicitly say that each thing should be it's own list

```
> L <- list()
> L[[a]] <- list()
> L[[a]][[b]] <- 1
> L
$a
$a$b
[1] 1
```

But it sounds like there is probably a better way to do what you want if you explain your actual goal.

Comment: actually I'd like to store the results (vectors of characters of variable length) of my analysis. To do the analysis I have several steps, say step a and b, and for each step I have used different methods, say a1, a2... and b1, b2... Finally I want to store them in a nested list. Using such list structure benefits subsequent analysis, format, and save by loops, also makes my workspace more compact and neat. thanks.

Comment: If there is an answer that works best for you feel free to click the "checkmark" next to that answer to signify that that answer helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

see help("[[")

*When $<- is applied to a NULL x, it first coerces x to list(). This is what also happens with [[<- if the replacement value value is of length greater than one: if value has length 1 or 0, x is first coerced to a zero-length vector of the type of value.*

Comment: Which explains what is going on but not how to fix it

Comment: @Sobala, ah I see, sorry didn't give a look at the help. thanks.